# monitoring and testing Internet of Things devices for security

Tags: networking, security, kali-linux, network-monitoring

My home network recently acquired a couple of IoT (internet of things) devices: a solar energy company hooked up a ethernet-connected telemetry gadget, and I put in a wifi-connected printer (made by the Brother company).

nmap told me the printer has an open web interface (80, 443). So I put a password on it. Cool.  nmap says the printer has an open telnet port. Not so cool.

The solar company's gadget also has an open web interface. But it's not clear how to secure it, or even if I have to.

There's been a lot of trouble recently with IoT stuff getting pwned by cybercriminals and enslaved into massive botnet attacks. ([Brian Krebs got hit](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/09/krebsonsecurity-hit-with-record-ddos/).) I want to prevent this on my little network, and to know if it's happening.  In other words, I'd love to white-hat hack my devices before a black hat gets a crack at them.

Do any utilities in Kali Linux do more than just say "hey, telnet's open"? Do any utilities probe for hard coded username/password combinations on random devices? Do any utilities monitor devices to detect when they've been pwned?

(Yes, they're behind a NAT in my router, and yes, I've closed up external access to the router. That *should* help. But cybercrooks are smarter and more motivated than I am. I just want to print an occasional photo and enjoy solar power).

Answer (score 1):

Being behind a firewall is your first line of defense.  Yes, hackers can bypass firewalls in many instances, but at least you have a wall that you can monitor.

From a continuous testing standpoint, check out [this company](http://www.myneo.co) for an easy 'have it done for you' approach on the cheap.

Otherwise, kali does have quite a few tools for you.  If you want to test usernames/passwords check our Hydra or Medusa brute force password testing tools.  These rely on a port/service to test though, so you will need to start with nmap to see what ports are actually open.

If you're curious how the IoT devices are communicating, fire up Wireshark to take a look at the traffic.  Hell, you might even end up seeing that they're hitting the Vendor API using clear text passwords, which isn't as uncommon as you would think for IoT devices.

Have fun!